# Weird redirections to URL with -

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, yoast

I'm getting weird redirections which aren't set up.

```
domain/sensual-masage → domain/sensual-masage-
```

There's problem with indexing the broken links with 301 redirections.
But there's not any redirection like this in .htacces. Also the links of posts are set up to be without the `-` symbol.

I'm using the Yoast SEO plugin so maybe there is the problem?

Comment: Hard to guess, what could cause an issue like this.

Comment: Disable the Yoast plugin, and test in a private browser tab (to exclude cached redirects misleading you) - if the problem is gone then, it was Yoast, if not, probably something else.

Comment: It's a theme/plugin problem then, try changing the theme, disable active plugins, then check.

Comment: I've disabled all plugins and changed the theme, still getting the redirections even in incognito mode. I'm using only yoast seo plugin + random sticky icons plugin. There was installed before caching plugin by my coworker WP Fastest Cache. Maybe after erasing it, it left some unwanted code somewhere?

Comment: To clarify it a bit more, this redirection showing up only in 6 of 130 posts.

Comment: And it is definitely an external 301 HTTP redirect? The link itself does not contain the trailing slash? Check the HTTP headers in the redirect response (and add these to your question) - this might give a clue as to what is generating the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Yoast SEO Premium there is a redirect tab and when a new link is added and or changed for a page it will create a redirect something to maybe have a check for.

Comment: No, I'm using the free version of Yoast SEO plugin.

Comment: @Pacislavek I would recommend going into the website via PhpMyAdmin and look for any redirects in the database this was you are seeing what WordPress sees as the database may be different to what you are seeing directly on your website.

Comment: "when a new link is added" - For a "new link", what does it redirect from/to?

Comment: @MrWhite Yoast SEO Premium tracks changes to existing permalinks so say for example you had a website https://mywebsite.co.uk/about-me but you hired someone and wanted to have staff profiles you would then change it to https://mywebsite.co.uk/about-us Yoast SEO will detect the change and create a redirect from one link /about-me to /about-us